# Can I select a datasource for all layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, data-source

I received a zip file with a QGZ map and all the layers that go into the map. When I open the map, it is not recognizing the sources for any of the layers, so I have to go through and individually select the datasource for each layers. It's A LOT of layers, so it would save me a lot of time if I could just select the folder where all the layers are and have it figure out the rest. I'm pretty sure you can do this is ArcMap. Is there a way to do this QGIS?

Comment: You could install *changeDataSource* plug-in to change the path of all layers in one step.

Comment: Open the QGIS project file in a text editor (not word/office) and do a find/replace on the server name, save the file, open it in qgis... we have had to do this before, and there are some other questions/answers on this forum with this info.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to unzip the .zip-archive, do not open the .qgz directly inside the archive. If you already did so, here a non-python answer:

1. Unzip your .qgz file using a zipping-software of your choice (7-Zip, WinZip, Winrar, ...)
2. You will receive a .qgs file
3. Create a Backup of it, just in case something goes wrong (or just unpack it again in case)
4. Open it with a texteditor of your choice (Notepad++, ...)
5. Choose "search and replace" (In Notepad++ on Windows its `Strg+F`)
6. Enter the outdated path with a leading `source="` to your layers as Search, and the new path with a leading `source="` as Replace
7. Open the .qgs file with QGIS and check if everything fine
8. If so, you can save it as .qgz if you wish to

for example search: `source="./old/path/to/files/`

and replace it with your new path: `source="./new/path/to/files/`